# Implementing BaseEntity class in c#

Tags: c#, class, object, properties

I'm trying to implement `BaseEntity` class in a c# and I've found example like this:

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity<T> : IBaseEntity<T>
 {
    public T Id { get; set; }
    object IBaseEntity.Id
    {
       get { return Id; }
    }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm wondering why is this example inheriting from Interface `IBaseEntity`, was this really needed?

What this piece of code acctually does?

```
object IBaseEntity.Id
{
    get { return Id; }
}
```

**This stuffs are really confusing me..**

Couldn't this be written simply like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> 
{
    public T Id { get; set; } // I guess this "T" means that this id might be of different type? like long, guid, int?

    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I guess it could be written like in this last example, but first example is more benefitial I guess? 
But I can't recognize why since I'm really beginner.

If someone could explain it to me I would appreaciate that so much!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> What this piece of code acctually does?

This is called explicit interface implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

By doing this, the method / property is only accessible via the interface type, not via the class type.

> Couldn't this be written simply like this:

Yes and no. It depends on the needs. In this case, I'd say the answer is no, because the `Id` on the interface is readonly. It appears the author intentionally made it like that so that it can only be read not write via the interface in types only know the interface.

It becomes writable on the class is the class's behavior, I guess, making the `Id` easy to set.

However, if the `Id` can be read and write, then it might be possible to not use the interface.

Comment: what does mean this that my prop Id is accessible via the interface and not via class type as you said: ? “By doing this, the method / property is only accessible via the interface type, not via the class type.”? Im really beginner in c# and Im trying to understand this. Thanks for help..

Comment: It means you will need to cast the class instance to the interface type in order to call `IBaseEntity.Id` implementation, e.g. `((IBaseEntity<T>)instance).Id`. If you go `instance.Id`, it is calling the `Id` property defined by the class.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out the definitions of the interfaces, which I assume are something like;

```cs
IBaseEntity{
    object Id { get; }
}
IBaseEntity<T>:IBaseEntity{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

The problem being solved here is not the implementation of `BaseEntity`, but the caller who wants to handle them. If you want to reference an instance of `IBaseEntity<T>`, your code will need to know what type `T` is. Forcing you to add generic override to every class / method, or a whole lot of reflection. However you can avoid that if you use the underlying `IBaseEntity` interface. eg;

```cs
    Dictionary<object, IBaseEntity> entities = ...;
    entities[e.Id] = e;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using an Interface for a Base Entity class leads to unnecessary code duplication. Instead use an Abstract Class. Perhaps something like the following:

```
namespace Domain;
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        var other = obj as BaseEntity;

        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (GetType() != other.GetType())
            return false;

        if (Id == 0 || other.Id == 0)
            return false;

        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BaseEntity a, BaseEntity b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BaseEntity a, BaseEntity b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (GetType().ToString() + Id).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I use this solution due to the three types of Equality.

- Identifier Equality
- Reference Equality
- Structural Equality

**Identifier Equality** means two Objects are equal if and only if they have the same Identity, like an Id.
**Reference Equality** means two Objects are equal if and only if they occupy the same location in memory
**Structural Equality** means two Objects are equal if and only if they are value-isomorphic, i.e. each of the objects fields are equal.

> Entities tend to exhibit Identifier and Referential Equality. Hence it only makes sense to use an Abstract class. Where Value Objects tend to exhibit Refere

Also keep in mind that Value Objects may also need their own Base class as well.